# How to avoid TextView/TextSwitcher update in setViewValue?

Tags: android, android-listview

I update the text of my TextSwitcher in the code of setViewValue. But in case database value is not changed, I would like to avoid its update.
Here is my current code:

```
public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
    int viewId = view.getId();
    switch(viewId) {
    case R.id.timetext:
         TextSwitcher twTime = (TextSwitcher) view;
         // something is wrong in the next line
         if (!cursor.getString(columnIndex).equals(getText(viewId)))
         {
            twTime.setText(cursor.getString(columnIndex));
         }
         return true;
```

Somehow, the data is still updated. Why?

Looks like `getText()` doesn't work properly with `TextSwitcher`. How to get its value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer.
First of all to get the text of `TextSwitcher` the following code should be used:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) twTime.getCurrentView();
if (!cursor.getString(columnIndex).equals(tv.getText().toString())) {
    twTime.setText(cursor.getString(columnIndex));
}
```

but prior to that

```
twTime.setCurrentText(cursor.getString(columnIndex));
```

should be used.