# Getting text from TextSwitcher

Tags: android, textview, textswitcher

How can I get the text in textswitcher which is previously set. Just like textview.getText(). I have tried the following code but didn't work.

```
TextSwitcher textSwitcher = (TextSwitcher)findViewById(...);
TextView currentlyShownTextView = (TextView) textSwitcher.getCurrentView();
String currentlyShownText = textSwitcher.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6089645/6414107) answer

```
TextSwitcher twTime = (TextSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.textSwotcher);
twTime.setCurrentText("your text");
TextView tv = (TextView) twTime.getCurrentView();
if (tv.getText().toString().length()>0) {
    //your action here
}
```